# Heroku: Stylesheet and Javascripts Not Updating for Rails 5 App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku, rails-assets

There have been many questions over many years where people have this issue. I have tried a combination of answers but I still can't get my updated stylesheet and javascript in my Rails 5.1.6 application to load in Heroku. It works on my local machine.

Here are my files.

**app/assets/stylesheets/application.scss**

```
*= require_tree .
*= require_self
```

**app/views/layouts/application.html.erb**

```
<html>
    <head>
      ......
      <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", media: "all" %>
      <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
      <%= favicon_link_tag "/favicon.ico" %>
      <%= render 'layouts/shim' %>
    </head>
    <body>
      ......
      <%= debug(params) if Rails.env.development? %>
      <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
    </body>
</html>
```

**config/application.rb**

```
require_relative 'boot'

require 'rails/all'

# Require the gems listed in Gemfile, including any gems
# you've limited to :test, :development, or :production.
Bundler.require(*Rails.groups)

module EzklwRor
  class Application < Rails::Application
    # Initialize configuration defaults for originally generated Rails version.
    config.load_defaults 5.1

    # Settings in config/environments/* take precedence over those specified here.
    # Application configuration should go into files in config/initializers
    # -- all .rb files in that directory are automatically loaded.

    RouteTranslator.config do |config|
      config.generate_unnamed_unlocalized_routes = true
      config.locale_param_key                    = :locale
    end

    config.exceptions_app = self.routes     
    config.action_dispatch.default_headers = { 'X-Frame-Options' => 'ALLOWALL' }
  end
end
```

**config/environments/production.rb**

```
Rails.application.configure do
  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb.

  # Code is not reloaded between requests.
  config.cache_classes = true

  # Eager load code on boot. This eager loads most of Rails and
  # your application in memory, allowing both threaded web servers
  # and those relying on copy on write to perform better.
  # Rake tasks automatically ignore this option for performance.
  config.eager_load = true

  # Full error reports are disabled and caching is turned on.
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true

  # We are using Rails ActionMailers in this application
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    domain:               'www.mydomain.com',
    address:              ENV["SMTPADDRESS"],
    port:                 587,
    user_name:            ENV["SMTPUSERNAME"],
    password:             ENV["SMTPPASSWORD"],
    authentication:       'plain' }

  config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true

  # Attempt to read encrypted secrets from `config/secrets.yml.enc`.
  # Requires an encryption key in `ENV["RAILS_MASTER_KEY"]` or
  # `config/secrets.yml.key`.
  config.read_encrypted_secrets = true

  # Disable serving static files from the `/public` folder by default since
  # Apache or NGINX already handles this.
  config.public_file_server.enabled = ENV['RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES'].present?

  # Compress JavaScripts and CSS.
  config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier
  # config.assets.css_compressor = :sass

  # Do not fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed.

  config.serve_static_assets = true

  config.assets.compile = true 

  config.assets.digest = true

  # `config.assets.precompile` and `config.assets.version` have moved to config/initializers/assets.rb

  # Enable serving of images, stylesheets, and JavaScripts from an asset server.
  # config.action_controller.asset_host = 'http://assets.example.com'

  # Specifies the header that your server uses for sending files.
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Sendfile' # for Apache
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Accel-Redirect' # for NGINX

  # Mount Action Cable outside main process or domain
  # config.action_cable.mount_path = nil
  # config.action_cable.url = 'wss://example.com/cable'
  # config.action_cable.allowed_request_origins = [ 'http://example.com', /http:\/\/example.*/ ]

  # Force all access to the app over SSL, use Strict-Transport-Security, and use secure cookies.
  config.force_ssl = true

  # Use the lowest log level to ensure availability of diagnostic information
  # when problems arise.
  config.log_level = :debug

  # Prepend all log lines with the following tags.
  config.log_tags = [ :request_id ]

  # Use a different cache store in production.
  # config.cache_store = :mem_cache_store

  # Use a real queuing backend for Active Job (and separate queues per environment)
  # config.active_job.queue_adapter     = :resque
  # config.active_job.queue_name_prefix = "ezklw_#{Rails.env}"
  config.action_mailer.perform_caching = false

  # Ignore bad email addresses and do not raise email delivery errors.
  # Set this to true and configure the email server for immediate delivery to raise delivery errors.
  # config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false

  # Enable locale fallbacks for I18n (makes lookups for any locale fall back to
  # the I18n.default_locale when a translation cannot be found).
  config.i18n.fallbacks = [I18n.default_locale]

  # Send deprecation notices to registered listeners.
  config.active_support.deprecation = :notify

  # Use default logging formatter so that PID and timestamp are not suppressed.
  config.log_formatter = ::Logger::Formatter.new

  # Use a different logger for distributed setups.
  # require 'syslog/logger'
  # config.logger = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(Syslog::Logger.new 'app-name')

  if ENV["RAILS_LOG_TO_STDOUT"].present?
    logger           = ActiveSupport::Logger.new(STDOUT)
    logger.formatter = config.log_formatter
    config.logger    = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(logger)
  end

  # Do not dump schema after migrations.
  config.active_record.dump_schema_after_migration = false
end
```

Here is what I have done on my local machine.

```
rake assets:clean

rake assets:precompile

rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production

committed changes with public/assets folder included using Github desktop app

git push heroku master

git push heroku master -f when initial change did not work after adding spaces to a file to avoid everything-up-to-date message.

heroku rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production

heroku restart several times along the way

heroku repo:clone -a myapp to verify that my app/assets folder was up to date

heroku repo:reset -a myapp to empty the heroku repo

git push heroku master

heroku logs -t
```

I have cleared the cache in my browser several times, rebooted my computer and displayed the new app on different devices. I see no errors in the heroku log. My css and js are not working. Where else can I look to fix this?

Comment: Could you share the environment variables with us?

Comment: @BerkhanBerkdemir, I definitely will. Which variables are you looking for?

Comment: Pamela, show the config/environments/production.rb and the application.rb files.

Comment: @TomConnolly, I've updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

I checked your configuration files, and in the `config/environments/production.rb` you have a mistake with `config.serve_static_assets = true`; therefore, you needed to change to `config.public_file_server.enabled = true`, and also, please change `config.assets.compile = false` because I don't think that you want to compile assets with every single request.

Here is similar usage: [config/environments/production.rb](https://github.com/magara/magara/blob/49b112ca464a5c907fb07be5027fbc59a5436783/config/environments/production.rb#L25)

For more information please check the same Q&A: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54376240/8929392

Comment: It did not work. I ended up creating a new Rails 5.2 app, copying the code I had and creating a new Heroku app. My code now works as expected. I added the serve_static_assets as suggested from another question which did not work. I had  config.serve_static_assets = true because Heroku was not updating my CSS & JS without it even with the public folder included in my git repo. I have concluded that the problem was a glitch in that specific Heroku application.

Comment: New Rails 5.2 comes with `config.public_file_server.enabled = ENV['RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES'].present?` and Heroku sets `RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES=enabled`. That is the reason the issue was fixed. However, I might be wrong.

Comment: Berkham, the later versions of 5.1 have config.public_file_server.enabled = ENV['RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES'].present?. I have never done anything with it. I just tried to change the CSS to another 5.1 apps and had the same problem with CSS updates. I upgraded it to 5.2 and my CSS is working in Heroku. I wonder if the problem is with the Heroku stack. My current Heroku apps are running Heroku-16. The new ones default to the new one Heroku-18. For future script or css changes I will upgrade my 5.1 apps to 5.2 and create new Heroku apps. I don't have a lot to change to get them working.